# Query inside the index page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

can i make a query inside the index view page which is list of items? Because i want to query the records of the other table using a "where clause" just getting the Id of selected item in the url and it will display also inside the index view page. If can make a query, I need an example. I am using asp.net mvc4. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

test controller

```
Function Index() As ActionResult
    Return View()
End Function

Function page(id As String) As ActionResult
    Return View()
End Function
```

.....  view pages ..
..... index .... `

```
<h2>Index</h2>


<a href="@Url.Content("~/Test/page/1")">1</a>
<a href="@Url.Content("~/Test/page/2")">2</a>
<a href="@Url.Content("~/Test/page/3")">3</a>
```

..... page page ....

```
    @Code
    ViewData("Title") = "page"
    Dim str = Request.Url.ToString()
    Dim laststr = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(str, 1)
    Dim vs As New Ve.VeDataSource
    ViewData("abc") = ((From r In vs.aspnet_Roles Order By r.RoleId Select    r.RoleName).Skip(laststr)).FirstOrDefault
End Code
<h2>page</h2>
<br />
@ViewData("abc")
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a code block in view page save the returned data of the query in a viewbag and you can use the ViewBag anywhere else.

Comment: Can you make an example? Thanks!